# Torah Scholars, Shirt Stains and the Death Penalty

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, chilul-kidush-hashem

[Shabbat 114a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.114a.3?lang=bi&with=Mishneh%20Torah,%20Human%20Dispositions&lang2=en):

> ואמר רבי חייא בר אבא אמר רבי יוחנן: כל תלמיד חכם שנמצא רבב על בגדו —
> חייב מיתה
>
> And Rabbi Chiyya bar Abba said that Rabbi Yochanan said: A Torah Scholar with a fat stain found on his clothes is liable for death

When Rambam [codifies this](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.5.9?lang=bi), he leaves out the death penalty. When Shulchan Aruch Harav [codifies this](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/not-to-be-dressed-sloppy-tucking-in-the-shirt/), he mentions the death penalty in the footnotes.

My question: how do we understand this "death penalty". Hyperbole? Real? Is it just reminding us that Chillul Hashem is a cause for being liable for death?

Comment: כָּל מְשַׂנְאַי אָהֲבוּ מָוֶת implies that they attract death, not that they are actually *chayav misah*.

Comment: The Talmud also says that those who don't listen to the words of the Sages deserve death -- chayyav mita.  We'd be dropping like flies if it meant exactly what it says. Besides, no death penalty can be imposed that is not explicitly mentioned in the Torah.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE how do Rabbis with fat/blood stains attract death?

Comment: They make the Torah repulsive.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE great, got it. Isn't that the same (or _very_ similar) to the reason why Chillul Hashem is חייב מיתה?

Comment: I think one relates to verbal reasoning and one is more visceral.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE didn't quite follow that sorry

Comment: Repulsion is a feeling. Scorn relates to verbal mental processing.